# Monitoring whether a Rest Service is Up and act accordingly

Tags: web-services, jakarta-ee, weblogic, osb

I have a requirement where we have to monitor a rest service. If the service endpoint is up then we will call respective service from that end point else we will put the values in local database.

I.e., if the Rest service is down we will perform the transaction by inserting into local database. Once the service is up we will take the data from local database and call the respective web service.

The technology that we use are Oracle Service Bus 11G and jdk 1.7.

Our application is deployed in Web logic server hosted in Linux machine.

How can I implement this in a better way?

Comment: Set a reasonable read/connection timeout value in your business service. Add a global error handler in your proxy server;  add a business service that use a JCA adapter that can connect to your local database,  If the target endpoint uri is not available capture the connection error raised by the service bus in your proxy service,  analyze the error in your error handler and then,  finally,  if it's a connection error, use your JCA based business service to add to your data your local database.

Comment: @Euclides: We cannot rely on connection time out because the web service response time is not constant. Also that will add to the latency if we reply on connection time out.

Comment: it is not a problem.  It will give connection timeout anyway in case the endpoint is not responding and it will raise an error that will be catched by your error handler.

Comment: But we cannot afford to wait for connection timeout. For connection timeout we have to wait for 30 seconds

Comment: hi @partha,  you are going to need other approach to know beforehand when the service is down. For example, mark the  non-responsive endpoint as offline permanently once it found out that it is down.

Answer (score 0):

Send first message without checking if service is available to see it's state. Then you know - if you receive some 2xx response or whatever you have there, you can keep sending, if you get some 5xx response then just wait/try again.